# The problem of inconsistency Datatable in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-livewire

In Laravel I use the datatable plugin for my tables. For the users view section, because I wanted the administrator to be able to see brief information about that user by clicking on a button on the same page. I used livewire, which by clicking on that button opens a modal with information from that user. But there is a problem, after the modal is opened, the table as a whole becomes a simple table like search or pagination Ever had this problem? Do you have a solution for it?

this is livewire view:

```
<div>
    <table class="datatable-init nk-tb-list nk-tb-ulist" id="jadval" name="jadval">
        <thead>
            <tr class="nk-tb-item nk-tb-head">
                <th class="nk-tb-col">
                    <span class="sub-text">نام کاربر</span>
                </th>
                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb">
                    <span class="sub-text">موجودی</span>
                </th>
                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                    <span class="sub-text">تلفن</span>
                </th>
                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg">
                    <span class="sub-text">وضعیت حساب</span>
                </th>
                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg">
                    <span class="sub-text">آخرین ورود</span>
                </th>
                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                    <span class="sub-text">وضعیت</span>
                </th>
                <th class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-tools text-right"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($Users as $user)
            <tr class="nk-tb-item" wire:key="{{$user->id}}" wire:ignore>
                <td class="nk-tb-col">
                    <div class="user-card">
                        <div class="user-info">
                            <span class="tb-lead">{{$user->name}}
                                <span class="dot dot-success d-md-none ml-1"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span>{{$user->email}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb">
                    <span class="tb-amount">{{ number_format($user->balance)}}
                        <span class="currency">تومان</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                    <span>{{$user->mobile}}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg" data-order="Email Verified - Kyc Unverified">
                    <ul class="list-status">
                        <li>
                            @if ($user->isVerified())
                            <em class="icon text-success ni ni-check-circle"></em>
                            <span>ایمیل</span>
                            @else
                            <em class="icon ni ni-alert-circle"></em>
                            <span>ایمیل</span>
                            @endif
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            @if ($user->fullActive())
                            <em class="icon text-success ni ni-check-circle"></em>
                            <span> احراز هویت </span>
                            @else
                            <em class="icon ni ni-alert-circle"></em>
                            <span>عدم احراز هویت</span>
                            @endif

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg">
                    <span>{{jdate($user->last_login_at)}}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                    @if ($user->isActive())
                    <span class="tb-status text-success">فعال</span>
                    @else
                    <span class="tb-status text-danger">غیرفعال</span>
                    @endif

                </td>
                <td class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-tools">
                    <ul class="nk-tb-actions gx-1">
                        <li class="nk-tb-action-hidden">
                            {{-- <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/2/mark/0" name="confirm-item" class="d-inline">
                            @csrf
                            <button typr="button" class="btn btn-trigger btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=" غیرفعال کردن">
                                <em class="icon ni ni-wallet-fill"></em>
                            </button>
                        </form> --}}
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-tb-action-hidden">
                            <button wire:click="selectItem({{$user->id}})" type="button" class="btn btn-trigger btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send Email">
                                <em class="icon ni ni-mail-fill"></em>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-tb-action-hidden">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-trigger btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Suspend">
                                <em class="icon ni ni-user-cross-fill"></em>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="drodown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-icon btn-trigger" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <em class="icon ni ni-more-h"></em>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                    <ul class="link-list-opt no-bdr">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <em class="icon ni ni-focus"></em>
                                                <span>Quick View</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <em class="icon ni ni-eye"></em>
                                                <span>View Details</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <em class="icon ni ni-repeat"></em>
                                                <span>Transaction</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <em class="icon ni ni-activity-round"></em>
                                                <span>Activities</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <em class="icon ni ni-shield-star"></em>
                                                <span>Reset Pass</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <em class="icon ni ni-shield-off"></em>
                                                <span>Reset 2FA</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <em class="icon ni ni-na"></em>
                                                <span>Suspend User</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- Modal Content Code -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="showUserModal" name="showUserModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <em class="icon ni ni-cross"></em>
            </a>
            <p id="idie" name="idie"></p>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem similique earum necessitatibus nesciunt! Quia id expedita asperiores voluptatem odit quis fugit sapiente assumenda sunt voluptatibus atque facere autem, omnis explicabo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer bg-light">
                <span class="sub-text">Modal Footer Text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is datatable code:

```
  NioApp.DataTable = function (elm, opt) {
    if ($(elm).exists()) {
      $(elm).each(function () {
        var auto_responsive = $(this).data('auto-responsive');
        var dom_normal = '<"row justify-between g-2"<"col-7 col-sm-6 text-left"f><"col-5 col-sm-6 text-right"<"datatable-filter"l>>><"datatable-wrap my-3"t><"row align-items-center"<"col-7 col-sm-12 col-md-9"p><"col-5 col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-left text-md-right"i>>';
        var dom_separate = '<"row justify-between g-2"<"col-7 col-sm-6 text-left"f><"col-5 col-sm-6 text-right"<"datatable-filter"l>>><"my-3"t><"row align-items-center"<"col-7 col-sm-12 col-md-9"p><"col-5 col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-left text-md-right"i>>';
        var dom = $(this).hasClass('is-separate') ? dom_separate : dom_normal;
        var def = {
          responsive: true,
          autoWidth: false,
          dom: dom,
          language: {
            search: "",
            searchPlaceholder: "برای جستجو تایپ کنید",
            lengthMenu: "<span class='d-none d-sm-inline-block'>نمایش</span><div class='form-control-select'> _MENU_ </div>",
            info: "_START_ -_END_ از _TOTAL_",
            infoEmpty: "اطلاعاتی یافت نشد",
            infoFiltered: "( مجموع _MAX_  )",
            paginate: {
              "first": "اول",
              "last": "قبلی",
              "next": "بعدی",
              "previous": "قبلی"
            }
          }
        },
            attr = opt ? extend(def, opt) : def;
        attr = auto_responsive === false ? extend(attr, {
          responsive: false
        }) : attr;
        $(this).DataTable(attr);
      });
    }
  };
```

and i added this code in layout view :

```
    @stack('before-scripts')
    <script src="/js/bundle.js?ver=2.2.0"></script>
    <script src="/js/scripts.js?ver=2.2.0"></script>

    @livewireScripts
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('name-updated', event => {
    $('#showUserModal').modal('show');
    $('#idie').text(event.detail.newName);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I had the same problem  what I did I put my model in html `iframe`

Comment: @Basharmal how?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565716/load-iframe-in-bootstrap-modal   and this https://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/arx9u    or this https://codepen.io/josephkes/pen/oBoZYv

Comment: the datatable code is in your script section?